# Set up users on Xubuntu with a workspace plugin and 2 workspaces

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I want to set up users on an Xubuntu desktop with a workspace plugin and 2 workspaces. I **do not** want to guide each of hundreds of users through *panel* -> *add item* -> *add workspace switcher*.

I have made a copy of `.config/xfce4` but that does not install the switcher.
If you install the switcher plugin via the gui then the `.config/xfce4` backup does set number, position etc.

Other distros e.g. openSUSE, Manjaro **do** setup the desktop with switcher enabled and 2 workspaces selected.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

## The panels

Install **Panel Profiles** in all the machines you want to customize:

`sudo apt install xfce4-panel-profiles -y`

### Replicating panels

1. Create your custom panel
2. Backup your panel(s) to your home folder using `xfce4-panel-profiles save ~/myPanel.bak`
3. Copy `myPanel.bak` to the home folder of the users you want to customize
4. For every user, load the configuration with `xfce4-panel-profiles load ~/myPanel.bak`

### Customize Workspaces

1. Set the amount of workspaces with `xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/workspace_count -s X`, where `X` is the number of workspace you want

You can probably script this [using ssh](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-enable-ssh-on-ubuntu-20-04/), but thats beyond the scope of this answer

---

Other userful `xconf` settings:

- Window Manager theme `xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/theme -s 'THEME_NAME'`
- GTK theme `xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName -s 'THEME_NAME'`
- Thunar location bar style `xfconf-query -c thunar -p /last-location-bar -s 'XXX'`, where `XXX` can be either `ThunarLocationButtons` or `ThunarLocationEntry`